# Assigning Returned Tuple to Different Columns of Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function, date_encode, that takes a date in the format (string) of year-month-day. The function parses this string and returns the day, month, and year as separate integers.

```
def date_encode(dateString):
    dateTimeObj = datetime.strptime(dateString, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return int(dateTimeObj.day), int(dateTimeObj.month), int(dateTimeObj.year)
```

This function currently returns a tuple. What I want to do is assign these three returned values to separate arrays, so that I would have separate "days", "months", and "years" arrays. When I try the following, I get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)" error:

```
days, months, years = data['Date'].apply(date_encode)
```

What is the most efficient way to do this properly (I will be going through hundreds of thousands of lines of this array).

Comment: Do you want to append to existing arrays or create three new arrays with one element in each?

Comment: I would want to create three new arrays! I am using a dataframe.apply() function, so it automatically applies the function to all N rows of the dataframe and returns N values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip(*iterables)`. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

**Here's an example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-04-24', '2019-05-25', '2019-06-26']})

def date_encode(dateString):
    dateTimeObj = datetime.strptime(dateString, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return dateTimeObj.day, dateTimeObj.month, dateTimeObj.year

df['day'], df['month'], df['year'] = zip(*df['Date'].apply(date_encode))
```

Input:

```
         Date
0  2019-04-24
1  2019-05-25
2  2019-06-26
```

Output:

```
         Date  day  month  year
0  2019-04-24    24       4   2019
1  2019-05-25    25       5   2019
2  2019-06-26    26       6   2019
```